# Variable to control how many lines print Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to use a variable to control the number of lines a script prints. I want to use the output variable and print only the number of lines the user requests. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
import sys, os

print ""
print "Running Script..."
print ""
print "This program analyzes word frequency in a file and"
print "prints a report on the n most frequent words."
print ""

filename = raw_input("File to analyze? ")
if os.path.isfile(filename):
  print "The file", filename, "exists!"
else:
  print "The file", filename, "doesn't exist!"
  sys.exit()
  print ""
output = raw_input("Output analysis of how many words? ")

readfile = open(filename, 'r+')

words = readfile.read().split()
wordcount = {}
for word in words:
  if word in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] += 1
  else:
    wordcount[word] = 1

sortbyfreq = sorted(wordcount,key=wordcount.get,reverse=True)
for word in sortbyfreq:
  print "%-20s %10d" % (word, wordcount[word])
```

Comment: How did you know about this feature of sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a counter in your final loop, which checks the number of loops done, and breaks when a certain number has been reached.

```
limit = {enter number}
counter = 0
for word in sortbyfreq:
  print "%-20s %10d" % (word, wordcount[word])
  counter += 1
  if counter >= limit:
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are essentially unordered, so you won't get anywhere trying to output elements after sorting by their frequency.

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

```
from collections import Counter
sortbyfreq = Counter(words)  # Instead of the wordcount dictionary + for loop.
```

You could then access the user defined most common elements with:

```
n = int(raw_input('How many?: '))
for item, count in sortbyfreq.most_common(n):
    print "%-20s %10d" % (item, count)
```